# Java - Reducing time spent in garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a program, that processes an input file, and allows actions to be performed on the resulting dataset. Due to the nature of the application, the memory footprint is pretty huge - several GB.

The program works great 90% of the time, however certain input files cause an unreasonable amount of time to be spent in garbage collection. Essentially the program spends a lot of time  creating objects that dont get used until the process is complete, at which point they are used. Essentially the memory keeps growing initially, then remains pretty constant. About 3 minutes into running the applications runtime, 99.9% of the time is spent on garbage collection, however there is almost no garbage to be collected (I have already checked for memory leaks). This seems to happen when approx 85% of the heap space is used and the heap stops growing. I don't know if the heap stops growing because no memory is availalble, or because the GC is taking too much time. I set a 5GB limit on heap space, and it grows to 3.6 before stalling.

My question is this. Given that I KNOW I have no (or very few memory leaks) and I know that my application will require a huge amount of memory, can I turn off, or at least reduce the aggressiveness of GC?

Comment: You could start by increasing the heap space limit.

Comment: I had to increase it to 32GB to get it to run, but it looks like this may be the only option. Its just frustrating that its only using 85% of the allocated space before it GC's out.

Comment: there are several gc implementations.. which one are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I find out something like that?

Comment: gc impl is set through system properties.. So if you are not setting a particular one, you should be using a default one.. Try this java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version

Comment: Need some code. You should be able to reduce your problem to a small code footprint and either show it to us or solve the problem yourself. Start removing stuff until the problem goes away.